# reset map location and direction

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a mapFragment and googlemap object in it. It is working fine. When user is exploring, rotating the map etc. they usually move off the current location.

Question : how to set the state of the map like it was, when it first loaded with showing current user at center of the map ?

I tried the below. That works, with current user at the center but if user rotated the map, that rotation is not reset, which should show North at top of the map.

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newLatLngZoom(new   LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude()),
                            15));
```

appreciate any help. This must be a simple scenario. I did search for this but didnt find working answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition`:

```
CameraPosition restoredCamera = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude()))
    .zoom(15)
    .bearing(0) // Face north
    .tilt(0) // reset tilt (directly facing the Earth)
    .build();

map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(restoredCamera));
```